# AngularJS - stream a default value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm new to angularjs and have a little problem to "stream" a allready givin value of a input field into another place of the same html document

for example:

```
<input type="text" name="headline" ng-model="headline"
class="form-control" placeholder="Your Headline"/> <-- No default value
```

and in another place:

```
<div class="header bg-blue preview">
     <h2 class="text-center">
              [[headline || "Your Headline"]]
     </h2>
</div>
```

This works perfect. When I enter something in the input field, the content is immediately passed to the .

My problem is, if the input field already has a default value, then this default value is not displayed because of the ng-headline.

Like this:

```
<input type="text" name="headline" ng-model="headline"
class="form-control" placeholder="Your Headline" value="blablabla"/> <-- with default value
```

As long as the "ng-headline" is in the , the "blabla" is not shown in the input field. When I remove the ng-headline, the string appears as default value in the input field.

I am writing an update function and the "old" data should already be in the input fields as value. And next to the Input field a preview is shown how the changes will look like. That's why I want to pass the changes to the preview with angular.js.

Comment: Just set ``$scope.headline = "blablabla"`` in your controller

Comment: Its hard to understand from your english. Can you please explain better with some more code. I have provided one answer as per my understanding. please check and confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tr `ng-value` or better try to set `$scope.headline` inside `controller.js` file itself

```
<input type="text" name="headline" ng-model="headline" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Headline" ng-value="blablabla"/>
```

Comment: ng-value haven't worked for me. The $scope thing is new to me :D Like I said, beginner. I will google it and try it :)

Comment: @dwdawdawdaw : cool, if you are still stuck, try to update your question with some plunkr code